# Does not exist in current context (Visual C#)

Tags: c#

I have an error coming up saying; The name 'map' does not exist in current context. What am I doing wrong?
Sorry I am quite new to coding...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        variables();
    }

    public static void variables()
    {
        string[,] map;
        map = new string[140, 140];

    }

    public static void updateMap(string[,] map)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a");
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        updateMap(map);

    }


}
```

Comment: Not sure why there are so many downvotes on this question; seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: I guess the downvotes are because the question is very, very basic, but you're right from a beginner perspective this might be a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

Create class variable string[,] map.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[,] map; 

    ...
```

so your variable "map" will be accessible in all(non-static) methods of this class

Comment: Might be useful if you provided an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your variable method.

```
public static void variables()
{
    string[,] map;
    map = new string[140, 140];

}
```

instead, keep it inside your class, so all the other methods may access it.

Think of the class as the parent. All the "methods" inside the class are its children. Everything inside of the children are its "things". Children don't like to share, specially with their brothers or sisters.

That being the case you want it somewhere where the parent has control of it, and the children have to follow the parent's rules of "sharing"

Like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[,] map;
    map = new string[140, 140];

    public Form 1: Form1()
    {
     ....
    }
    private void Form1_Load()
    {
     .....
    }
    public static void updateMap()
    {
     .....
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
    .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared `map` inside the context of the `variables` method (not sure what this method is even for). As a result, this variable is not accessible anywhere outside of that method. You need to declare it as a class property, like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[,] map;
    ...
}
```

Then, initialize this on your `Load` method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    map = new string[140,140];
}
```

You can then do away with the `variables` method and reference this property from inside your other methods as you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `map` is only valid in this method because it is declared within:

```
public static void variables()
{
    string[,] map;
    map = new string[140, 140];

}
```

If it should be valid for the whole class, just declare it as a field:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[,] map;

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    ...
}
```

But this is very, very basic. I highly recommend to read a book about C#:

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=c%23